# Error while merging two line segments

Tags: qgis, line, merge, error

When I'm tryong to merge two line segments in QGIS, I get this error:

> Invalid result: Could not store value 'Skipped' in field of type
> Integer64.

What does this mean?

One example is showned in the picture below. I select two features, go to `Edit > Merge selected features`, and then the error.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That there's an issue with your attributes, which we can't help resolving without example data.

Comment: Added an example to the original post. When I try to merge the two lines shown, it end up with the error.

Comment: That are screenshots, but not example data. Anyway, have you tried `repair geometries`?

Comment: Sorry. Thought thar you meant just an example. What is example data? The GPKG-file?

I haven't tried reoair geometric. Will do that now.

Comment: Tried the repair geometries-function, but that did not solve the problem. I stille get the same error when merging.

Comment: What happens when you remove all attribute columns and then try the merge?

Comment: After removing the attributes it merges perfectly. But how do I find the error in the attribute table? I do need the attributes as well as the geometry.

Comment: Delete the first half of the attributes, try merge. If it works, delete the third quarter, try merge - else delete the first quarter, try merge. etc, pp.

Comment: I tried removing the FID column, and merging worked fine after that. Så apparently that is where the error is located.